# Spectral function of superconductor in the BEC regime: how does Higgs mechanism affect the spectrum?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, symmetry-breaking, superfluidity, goldstone-mode

Consider the standard BCS theory but assume that the interaction energy $U$ that enters the definition of gap parameter (i.e. $\Delta = (U/N)\sum_k \langle c_{-k\downarrow} c_{k\uparrow} \rangle$, where $N$ is the number of sites) is large compared to the Fermi energy (BEC regime).
The zero-temperature gap equation in this limit can be simply solved to give $\Delta(0) = U/2$, so I would expect that the critical temperature scales accordingly $T_c \approx \Delta(0) \approx U$.
However, we know that mean field theory does not capture the Goldstone mode (corresponding to fluctuations of the phase), hence I would expect that, as long as the superfluid is charge-neutral, there are low lying excitations of the phase field that cost less energy than the energy required to break a pair and so I would expect a much lower critical temperature.

**First question**: is this idea correct? Can I intuitively guess how $T_c$ scales with $U$ in this case? My guess, based on some literature, is $T_c \approx 1/U$ because the superfluid stiffnes (or superfluid density) at zero temperature goes as $1/U$.

Now comes the **real question**: how is the picture above modified for a charged superfluid, where the minimal coupling to a gauge field must be included in the theory to ensure gauge invariance?
In this case there is the Anderson-Higgs mechanism, i.e. the gauge field becomes massive, but it is not very clear to me what happens to the Goldstone mode... I guess it simply does not exist anymore? So in this case should I expect $T_c \approx U$ as if no Goldstone mode exists whatsoever?

**More details**
In case my question is not clear enough, I would also appreciate a description of the spectral function beyond mean-field BCS theory. In the latter case, there is just a spectral gap that increases with $U$. If we include Goldstone mode on a neutral superfluid, the gap is filled by energy states corresponding to collective modes (is this right? can you sketch how?). How is the spectral function modified when the superfluid is charged?
Bonus: I guess that the single-particle spectral function $-\frac{1}{\pi} \mathrm{Tr}\mathrm{Im}G(\omega + i 0^+)$, where $G$ is the Green function, cannot capture the collective modes, so what should I calculate to see the collective modes?

Any help, even partial answers, are very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean in this sentence "...we know that mean field theory does not capture the Goldstone mode"? Could you please clarify? Do you mean that Higgs mode corresponds to the gap modulus, whereas Goldstone mode corresponds to the gap phase? To capture collective modes it is possible to consider two particle Green function. Also, I assume that ARPES can be used.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, by Goldstone mode I mean the space-time fluctuations of the gap phase, I have edited accordingly